# Condition of if statement always evaluating to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to add a class to a few cells in a table if their numeric value is greater or equal to a certain value.

This is the code I have. `re` is the threshold for adding the class.

```js
$("#battersTable td.runs").each(function() {
    if($(this).html() >= re) {
        $(this).addClass("elite");
    }
});
```

However, the condition of the `if` statement always appears to be evaluating to `true` and the class is always being added! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `re` mean in `>= re`

Comment: If the statement is executed, that *means the condition is `true`*. Not the `if` statement is the problem, your condition is.

Comment: sorry, it is a variable that is defined earlier. Ive checked the values or this.html and re and they are correct at the time of the if statement but it is being entered regardless of the condition.

Comment: The if statement is being entered when re is < this.html

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for `if(parseInt($(this).html(), 10) >= re)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
if ($(this).html() >= re)
```

is likely not doing what you want it to do.

If these are supposed to be numbers for a numeric comparison, then you need to parse the string into a number (and re must be a number too) before doing a numeric comparison:

```
if (parseInt($(this).html(), 10) >= re)
```

An example of what both `re` is and what `$(this).html()` is would allow us to give more specific answers.

Comment: thank you! i didnt realize this.html was returning a string thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what is the second argument 10 here inside parseInt ?

Comment: In case the returned HTML is a numeric value, it shouldn't be a problem (although I'd too consider it a good idea). See: http://jsfiddle.net/qKUSh/

Comment: Perhaps you need to discover [MDN for great javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on lots of javascript and DOM things.  Also, simply typing parseInt into Google will answer your question too.  The second parameter to `parseInt()` is the radix that it uses for converting string to number.  Decimal numbers are base 10 (radix of 10), hex numbers are base 16, binary base 2, octal base 8, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**Guesses:**

- your problem is that when you run this again, classes are not removed
- you know what `re` is and that there can be no problem with it, that is why you don't show it

**If these are right,** [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) should help you:

```
$("#battersTable td.runs").each(function() 
{
    $(this).toggleClass("elite", $(this).html() >= re);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will works

```
$("#battersTable td.runs").each(function() 
{
    var val = $(this).html();
    if(val == 're')
    {
       $(this).addClass("elite");
    }
});
```

here `re` is a string and you can't use >= in a string.